# Return file with nginx if exists, pass to proxy else

Tags: nginx

The task is to get argument with filename from query params, check if file exists, and:

- If exists, return this file
- Else, pass the request to Django backend

I've managed to get the param and check if file exists, but I doesn't know what to do next:

```
location /media/ {
                set     $file "/static/$arg_key";

                if (-f $file) {
                        // Return the file
                } else {
                        // include proxy_params;
                        // proxy_pass      http://unix:/opt/django/gunicorn.sock;
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what `try_files` is for.

For example:

```
location /media/ {
    try_files /static/$arg_key @django;
}

location @django {
    proxy_whatever...;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible that something like "../etc/.../" may be passed to "key" argument and will lead sensitive information disclosure?

Comment: Maybe so. That part of your URL design doesn't make much sense anyway, and you should probably just use normal URLs where the path is in the path part.

Comment: Seems that it doesn't work — it passes the request to proxy every time, instead of returning existing file.

Comment: OK, then I'll go back to: Use a more sensible URL design.

Comment: In fact, it's a web app that thumbnails external images and I thought to use "key" argument to serve already thumbnailed images. If image is not thumbnailed yet, request (with another parameters such as original image URL and desired size) should be passed to Django backend that creates thumbnail and returns it. So I don't know how to design this better :(

Comment: @user59178 You don't really need arguments for that at all. Just choose a path and write the static files to it if they aren't present, and maybe occasionally delete them when they expire.